# Adding custom html to 2columns-left.phtml issue

Tags: layout, html

I want to add a custom html to different pages using the 2columns-left.phtml.This is the my code:

```
   <?php 
            $request = $this->getRequest();
            $module = $request->getModuleName();
            $controller = $request->getControllerName();
            $action = $request->getActionName();
            if($module == 'customer' && $controller == 'account' && $action == 'index'){
        ?>
            <div class="header-page-custom">
                <div class="header-custom">
                    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Dashboard') ?></h1> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
            }
            if($module == 'customer' && $controller == 'account' && $action == 'edit'){
        ?>
            <div class="header-page-custom">
                <div class="header-custom">
                    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Test') ?></h1> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
```

So, I want to avoid that if conditions. Is there another way to add this header html to different pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `layout handler`.

As per as ur comment,you want to add this code whenever router url are

- customer/account/index
- customer/account/edit

In your case  customer_account_index & customer_account_edit are  handler for respective url

```
<customer_account_index>
    <reference name="root"> <!-- as you want to add  -->
    <-- call a block by creating new phtml -->
            <block type=core/template" name="textno" template="customer/account/test.phtml" />

    </reference>
</customer_account_index>


<customer_account_edit>
    <reference name="root"> <!-- as you want to add  -->
    <-- call a block by creating new phtml -->
            <block type=core/template" name="textno" template="customer/account/test1.phtml" />

    </reference>
</customer_account_edit>
```

Then call this file at  2columns-left.phtml by below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('textno')?>
```

Comment: I have aprox 20 pages with differents headers. Do I have to create 20 .phtml files ? All of the pages are using the 2columns-left.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create condition statements in `.phtml` (that's horrible code!). I think you should have a good read about Magento layouts, that's the right (and clean) way to do it:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/